# Configuring kernel

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

After create a new system call, how to update the kernel?

I tried these lines,

```
make-kpkg clean
fakeroot make-kpkg -initrd -append-to-version=-custom kernel_image kernel_headers
```

But Ubuntu asked me if I am sure what I am doing, or not. But I am not sure. Do I have to say yes? Here is what did, Ubuntu said to me:

> You are attempting to install a kernel
>   image (version 2.6.25.4-us122l)
>   However, the directory
>   /lib/modules/2.6.25.4-us122l/kernel
>   still exists. If this directory
>   belongs to a previous
>   linux-image-2.6.25.4-us122l package,
>   and if you have deselected some
>   modules, or installed standalone
>   modules packages, this could be bad.

I agree with Ubuntu. This could be bad. How can I recompile the kernel? Second question is, after writing a system call, do I have to install debian files?

Comment: What do you mean by "new system call"?? Why would you want to do that? Are you trying to learn about OS programming?

Comment: I just wrote then added a system call. i can't implement that because i can not update the kernel.

Comment: Your debian packaging of the kernel is correct. afaik.
Have you installed the kernel manually before? It looks like the installer see files there, and prevent you to install a new kernel there.

Comment: I installed before. But i want to recompile the kernel. After recompiling, i tried to install again.

Comment: I would suggest you remove the files/directory you installed manually before you install the debian package.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to avoid clashing with your installed kernel is to configure yours with an additional version string.